# Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner Even with correct rDNS entry

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, smtp, reverse-dns, amazon-route53

I know this will looks like a duplicate question. But asking this after trying every possible solution I can apply. But still no luck. I've configured many domains like this and none given this error. Only possible issue came across is that when I requested Amazon to configure the rDNS, they made it to safetyseek.nz instead of rdns.safetyseek.nz. Really appreciate any help I can get.

[image]

Comment: Your IP address resolves to rdns.safetyseek.nz. It is your computer's hostname that is set incorrectly.

Comment: The strange thing is I did the same for uat.safetyseek.nz which works fine. And it resolves to rdns.uat.safetyseek.nz. https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3auat.safetyseek.nz&run=toolpage#